# Can we hide or delete report rows in SSRS report while we render it to excel?

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to delete or hide a  particular row in a table item just in excel rendering of the report. I have a  summary report , which  has a link to its detail report(drill through), when i export the summary report to excel i would like to delete the row with link becasue it wont work from excel . any idea?

Thanks for your time.
San

Answer (score 1):

If your going to export to CSV you could set the DataElementOutput to none. I don't think there is any easy to do this to hide the report in excel. One thing you can try is to make the URL work. I bet the report is using the internal name of the server. There should be a way to configure ssrs to use a FQDN.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with Josh. In short there isn't an easy way to do it. You could potentially write and install your own plug-in to use instead of the excel output, but this would be pretty time intensive.

Answer (score 0):

if your users know that they want to export to excel/csv, you could just create a new report without the links, but a link on the summary report to the new report you jsut created, and have them export from there.

Comment: oh yeah, jsut thought of this.  you can programatically set up groups and rows to go hidden, and then set a parameter to pass to them to make them hidden or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  But i would like to have the link shown in the summary reports HTML rendering , but not in that reports excel version. how will i use this parameter for that ,wont that hide my link  in the HTML version itself?
please be precise.
Thanks

Comment: what you do is you have a parameter (bit) that sets itself to True, and then on the fields that you want to show or hide you set up an expression on the visibility with that parameter (right click - properties - visibility).  As far as I am aware you and set it to true or false when they export, but the user can change the parameter themselves to hide the field when they want to export.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, 

 here i dont want the user to involve in this,they should be just using the export option in thr toolbar. Most of them wont get this point, selecting the appropriate parameter before exporting.
Thanks,San